# Default URL is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter framework. I am using HMVC design pattern

I have a issue with base url when I enter URL like this **https://sitename/** its show blankpage and

when enter URL like this **https://sitename/controller** then show it main page of website

**Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://sitename/';
```

**Routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'notify/show_404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
Options -Indexes
```

How to show main page of website on this URL **https://sitename/**

Comment: Try to replace with this
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] => RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: this not working

Comment: Your default controller home is in same controller folder directory or in controller/other_folder ?

Comment: sitename > application > controllers > Home.php

Comment: have you set `$config['index_page'] = '';` ? AND I use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] `

Comment: this is also not working